# should I vote to close this question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

should I vote to close this question:

[No POST response when using checkbox form in my Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893462)

Doesn't seem to add much as the things that need to be done to fix the code include a lot of very basic problems. I suspect this question adds nothing to SO.

It certainly dropped me in a tarpit trying to anser it.

Comment: While not the best question in the world, it *is* a question, and a reasonable one at that. It has the potential to help future visitors so IMHO, this question is not quite bad enough to warrant closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it a clear and reasonable question, so I don't see any need to vote for close. I however know nothing about Python/Django, so I can't tell if the OP's code is helpful in understanding the problem better.

Anything can be asked on SO as long as the programming problem/question is clearly elaborated. If the problem couldn't be clearly understood without a code snippet, you'd just post a comment to ask the OP for relevant snippets. If the problem couldn't be understood at all because it is poorly described and would basically boil down to "I have a form with checkboxes and it doesn't work!", then I'd vote for close as "Not a real question".

Comment: okay thanks, i'll leave it be. it is certainly possible to point out some obvious flaws/fixes that would mean the OP's code definitely won't work, and I guess that's something.